# Always getting a "Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement" error while working on any of the keyboard actions of the actions class in protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am always getting a "Failed: sendKeysToActiveElement" error while working on any of the keyboard actions of the actions class in protractor.

Below is my code -

```
it(' Tests to handle keyboard actions in Protractor ', async () => {
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);
browser.get("https://letcode.in/selectable")
browser.sleep(5000)

let elem_1 = element(by.xpath("(//h3[@id='clour'])[2]"))
    let elem_2 = element(by.xpath("(//h3[@id='clour'])[4]"))
    let elem_3 = element(by.xpath("(//h3[@id='clour'])[5]"))
    let elem_4 = element(by.xpath("(//h3[@id='clour'])[9]"))

await browser.actions()
    .click(await elem_1.getWebElement())
    .keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
    .click(await elem_2.getWebElement())
    .keyUp(protractor.Key.CONTROL)
    .perform();
});
```

My conf.js -

```
require("babel-register")({
presets: ["es2015"]
});

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true,
specs: ['selectMultiElement.js'],
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['show-fps-counter=true', '--window-size=1920x1280']
    }
}
};
```

I am getting the error as -
UnsupportedOperationError: sendKeysToActiveElement
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-HGJU6DES', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Can anyone suggest what can be the solution of this error please.

I am using chrome 102 version.

I tried adding 'w3c': false in chromeOptions but that also showed some different error. Running the code with this argument it is opening 3 instances of the chromedriver but not being able to proceed with any command in the script thus eventually failing the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the framework from jasmine to jasmine2 worked for me.